# inconsistent time elapsed in java

Tags: java, time, int

I am trying to compute time lapsed in java using nanoTime.  But everytime it gives me different results.  Why it is not consistent always ?

**Sample code :**

```
long startTime=System.nanoTime();
String.valueOf(number).length();
long endTime = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println(endTime-startTime);
```

Comment: Mandatory comment; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: Why do you need this to be consistent?

Comment: Well, because the CPU load and *state* is not always the same (varies each time). As @Gosu suggests, this is not the right way of doing a proper  micro benchmarking

Comment: Such a code can never give a consistent time; as @defectus says, you have to ask yourself why you need this to be consistent. This looks like a XY problem, so what is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: For consistency, compute time lapsed using milliseconds rather than nanoseconds.

Comment: Well, i am in a situation where i need to compute this time elapsed to nano precision. @defectus yes, i don't need it to be consistent. I asked it here to get more hands-on exp to this qst.I will go through the link to understand it better

Answer (score 6):

`nanoTime()` and its sister `currentTimeMillis()` are not exact and depending on the architecture you run your code on they suffer from rounding (see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--) for details):

```
This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond resolution 
(that is, how frequently the value changes) -
no guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good
as that of currentTimeMillis().
```

If you measure the time in order to decide if alternative a or b is faster you are basically doing a micro benchmark. There are frameworks for this and you should use them. Probably the one most known for Java is [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). If you need to do the same for larger code parts you might consider profiling.

You might want to have a look at this stackoverflow post: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

The lapsed time will vary depending upon how JVM will execute and allocate the processing time to the thread in which this code executes.
I tried multiple runs and always got result in between 9000 to 11000 nanoseconds range. This looks fairly consistent.